# Error in Mergesort function in mips assembly

Tags: mips

```
# Merge Sort Function

merge_sort:

    # Input: $a0 = address of the array to be sorted
    #        $a1 = size of the array
    # Output: Sorted array in memory

    # Base case: If the array has 0 or 1 elements, it is already sorted.
    beq $a1, 1, end_merge_sort
    
    # Calculate the middle index
    srl $t0, $a1, 1
    
    # Recursively sort the left half of the array
    move $a1, $t0
    jal merge_sort
    
    # Calculate the address of the right half
    mul $t0, $t0, 4
    add $a0, $a0, $t0
    div $t0, $t0, 4
    
    # Recursively sort the right half of the array
    move $a1, $t0
    jal merge_sort
    
    # Merge the two sorted halves
    move $t2, $a0         # $t2 = address of the left half
    move $t3, $t0         # $t3 = size of the left half
    add $t3, $t3, $t3     # $t3 = size of the left half * 2
    add $t2, $t2, $t3     # $t2 = address of the right half
    move $t4, $a1         # $t4 = size of the right half
    add $t4, $t4, $t4     # $t4 = size of the right half * 2
    move $t5, $a0         # $t5 = address of the merged array
    
    merge_loop:
        beqz $t3, copy_right
        beqz $t4, copy_left
    
        lw $t6, 0($a0)     # Load element from the left half
        lw $t7, 0($t2)     # Load element from the right half
    
        # Compare elements and copy the smaller one to the merged array
        blez $t6, copy_left
        blez $t7, copy_right
    
        compare_copy:
            # Copy from the left half
            sw $t6, 0($t5)
            addi $t5, $t5, 4
            addi $a0, $a0, 4
            addi $t3, $t3, -4
            j merge_loop
    
        copy_left:
            # Copy from the left half
            sw $t6, 0($t5)
            addi $t5, $t5, 4
            addi $a0, $a0, 4
            addi $t3, $t3, -4
            j merge_loop
    
        copy_right:
            # Copy from the right half
            sw $t7, 0($t5)
            addi $t5, $t5, 4
            addi $t2, $t2, 4
            addi $t4, $t4, -4
            j merge_loop`
    
    end_merge_sort:
        jr $ra
```

I think there is an error here which is giving the exception 6 (Bad Instruction Address).

The expected thing is that in my overall code it should take an array as input and sort it using the mergesort function but it is throwing an Exception 6

I am unable to find the error even after debugging manually.